# Coded UI Control.Exists. System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I want to check that window exists after some actions.
I try:

```
 protected override Boolean IsPresent()
    {
        if (_mainWindow == null)
        {
            _mainWindow = new WinWindow();
            _mainWindow.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "MainWindow";
        }
        return _mainWindow.Exists;
    }
```

But if control does not exist `mainWindow.Exists` throws System.NullReferenceException. I can't understand why it happens because mainWindow reference in this code can't be null.
How can I verify is _mainWindow founded or not?

I've did it to wait for window loading with timeout. I've also tried to use `MainWindow.FindMainWindow().WaitForControlExist(100000)` but it doesn’t wait needed timeout.
This code also not set my needed timout:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 100000;
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyTimeout = 100000;
```

I use VS2013.

UPD:

This is my code with NRE check:

```
protected override Boolean IsPresent()
{
    if (_mainWindow == null)
    {
        _mainWindow = new WinWindow();
        _mainWindow.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "MainWindow";
    }
    try
    {
        return _mainWindow.TryFind(); //TODO WTF?
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We've got a NullReferenceException");
        Console.WriteLine("_mainWindow reference is " + ((_mainWindow == null) ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL"));
        throw e;  //Line 41
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

```
We've got a NullReferenceException
_mainWindow reference is NOT NULL
Attachments:

file:///Project/TestResults/User_WIN-FP7FMM7PUB1%202017-04-09%2015_57_34/In/4acd6ac8-92ce-4746-8787-3aecfd63bdd8/WIN-FP7FMM7PUB1/SuccessLoginTest.png

Test method UITest.AutoTests.LoginTests.SuccessLoginTest threw exception: 

System.NullReferenceException: object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   in UITest.Locators.MainWindow.IsPresent() in MainWindow.cs: line 41
   in UITest.Locators.BaseWindow.Wait() in BaseWindow.cs: line 34
   in UITest.Locators.MainWindow..ctor() in MainWindow.cs: line 18
   in UITest.Locators.LoginWindow.ClickEnterButton() in LoginWindow.cs: line 57
   in UITest.AutoTests.LoginTests.SuccessLoginTest() in LoginTests.cs: line 32
```

Comment: The original exception is that `_mainWindow.Exists` gives a null. That does not mean that `_mainWindow` is null. It is likely that the code in either the implicit `_mainWindow.Find()` or in the `Exists` property is throwing. The fact that `_mainWindow.TryFind()` also throws suggests that the implicit `Find` is failing. These ideas make me wonder what sort of window is being used. How has the application been made? Is it a standard Windows application? Does it use Custom Controls? Coded UI is quite reliable with the usual Microsoft application types but it  (...continued)

Comment: relies on support code within those types. That support code is only used by Coded UI (and similar accesses), it is not used in normal execution. Perhaps your application is based on non-Microsoft that does not properly support Coded UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in version of VS2013.
I have installed Update 5 and now TryFind() returns False if object not found.

Answer (score 0):

Exists is not what you want to use.  You can use TryFind() instead.

```
 protected override Boolean IsPresent()
 {
     if (_mainWindow == null)
     {
         _mainWindow = new WinWindow();
         _mainWindow.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "MainWindow";
     }
     return _mainWindow.TryFind();
 }
```

For more examples of how to use Coded UI to do various tasks, see my website [codeduiexamples.com](http://codeduiexamples.com)

Comment: _mainWindow.TryFind() throws System.NullReferenceException too.

Comment: are you sure that's where the NRE is being thrown?

Comment: Yes, exception in this line: _mainWindow.TryFind(). Thank you for answer.

Comment: Can you please wrap that line in a Try block and grab a screen shot?  I'm having a hard time believing that's what is throwing an NRE.

Comment: I just did a simple test to TryFind() something that was not on screen and it simply returned false for me.

Comment: Please remove "if (_mainWindow == null)" so that you are newing up and see if that fixes it.  Can you include where _mainWindow is defined and any other places where it is set?